# Is it common to test out a parkour route to make sure it's safe first?

Tags: safety, parkour

I enjoy practicing parkour by exploring and being on the move. But at the same time I'm conscious of my inexperience and safety as well. I much more enjoy linking several moves together and creating a momentum, but I'm always thinking about things like: what if that rail won't hold my weight or it's too slippery, what if there's a loose brick on that wall and I slip etc.

I usually end up just taking a bit of time to examine the route I'm about to take first and do a few test runs to make sure there aren't any hazards waiting to snag me. I haven't seen a lot of parkour videos talk about this sort of thing so I'm not sure what this is called or if it's even something that's common to do? I understand that a proper indoor facility is more safe, but I enjoy outdoors much more and at some point whatever you practice indoors needs to get applied outdoors anyway otherwise what's the point.

So my question is, is it common to test out a parkour route to make sure it's safe first? And if so, what sort of things should I look for first? I kind of see this as an equivalent to "PK Vision", except it's "potential hazard that could break your neck Vision".

Comment: Be sure to test it or this will happen to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VhnU3_-KUY

Comment: @SurpriseDog sure thanks for that. Are you able to turn your comment into an answer and perhaps add some tips common ways to look for potential hazards or things to stick to if you're not sure. That would make the answer for helpful for others I think

Comment: https://youtu.be/emyOQ-RDG-E?t=281

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, when training ALWAYS check your surfaces. The only time you wouldn't is if you're in a life and death situation, but that's not training. Most parkour videos where there is talking mention or show this. Storror would say "check your surfaces" at least once every other video.

As you're starting out, make sure you check your takeoff and landing, test your shoe's grip on it, shake it to make sure it's stable and check for any individual lose bricks. With time you'll be able to tell a lot about the safety of a surface at a glance and a brief tap, so these checks will get easier and faster.

Even then be prepared for things to break or come lose when you least expect them, so practising ukemi (the skill of bailing/falling safely) will reduce risk of injury even further. Spend some time deliberately jumping to loose, unsecured obstacles like bricks standing on their side or wooden crates or even things with wheels that can move. Deliberately practice jumping to wet, slippery, icy surfaces. This will allow your body to learn how the various forces work, which direction things will move and how to counteract them safely.